# Change sprite's image in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm working on a program where I have a group() with sprites in them. I start by adding each sprite to the group and passing an image for each sprite. Is it possible loop through each sprite in the group and changing the image of a sprite if a certain criteria is met (if statement), or would you need to remove the whole group and create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that you can run pygame.image.load() again to change the image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. class `pygame.sprite.Group` has a method `update()` which you can call to update all the sprites in a group. In the `update()` method of each sprite in the group you have to define what you want to do with each sprite (you can change the image here).

I hope it will be of help to you.